# Passing List of integers and text in to Postgres Function

Tags: postgresql

creating a function which can pass table names and also the list of integer values in to postgreSQL
its executing succesfully

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.join1(table1 text[],table2 text[],emp_num integer[])  
RETURNS TABLE( Date date, emp_num int, sal text,LOCATION text,Country text,gender text ) as  
$BODY$  
BEGIN  
 SELECT a."Date",a."emp_num",a."sal",a."gender" ,b."LOCATION",b."Country" FROM my_schema.table1 a  
LEFT JOIN my_schema.table2 b  
 ON a."emp_num" = b."emp_num"  
 WHERE a."emp"  = ANY(emp_num);  

END;  
$BODY$  
 LANGUAGE PLpgSQL;
```

But while calling the function by passing parameters which are combination of text and list of integers,getting the below error

```
SELECT * FROM my_schema.join1('emp_table','add_table',array[1269,652,105]);
```

ERROR:

```
"Array value must start with "{" or dimension information."
```

any modification's will be appriciated

Comment: The first two arguments of your function are text **arrays** but you call it with **scalar** argument values. That makes the engine think the arguments are textual array expressions, which must start with, well, what the message tells you. You don't even seems to use the first two arguments in the functions body at least as posted. So they don't make much sense and can just be removed from the function's definition.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names